# Installing R on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: r, ubuntu

I am trying to install R on ubuntu 20.04. using the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/'
```

I get the following error.

> E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rdev/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a
> Release file.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

When I tried to run R in the terminal, I get the following message

> Command 'R' not found, but can be installed with:

Could you please help with the installation of R on Ubuntu

Comment: Did you follow all of the instructions at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a slash in your ppa link. The correct command is

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/focal-cran40/'
```

Just a little advise: don't just copy everything from a guide or tutorial you read, try to actually understand it. And more importantly don't add random ppas you didn't at least look over. Thats quite the security issue.

Comment: Got this error  Error: 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/focal-cran40/' invalid

Comment: Both of the official R ubuntu install guides use the same syntax as the OP i.e. don't add in another slash; see https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/fullREADME.html or https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: Yes you're right, my mistake. Actually I recommend following the official [guide](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) to add the ppa

Comment: Fallowed the official guide. Here is the output.

Comment: Did you import the signing key? `apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9`

Comment: Hit:9 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ InRelease
Err:10 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu focal/ Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.226.106.122 80]

Comment: Yes imported the key

Comment: Did you execute the commands as sudo? So in front of every command in the guide add sudo. Otherwise I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. I just followed the steps in the guide as written.